# what is the meaning of [1] at the end when using json.loads?

Tags: python

in this test code sample:

```
import httplib2
import json
url="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo? 
     access_token=61651651651"
h=httplib2.Http()
test1=json.loads(h.request(url,'GET')[1])
```

i don't understand what is the meaning of [1] in the last line, if i use [2] for example i get an error IndexError: tuple index out of range, [0] gives me TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'Response', so every time i load json response i have to use [1]?

Comment: Since you asked, that's your answer. Though  I suspect your actual issue may be uncovered once you decide to share more than one line of code.

Comment: Seems like you are passing object of type `Response` to `json.loads`. It only accepts `bytes` or `str`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Bad dupe, this isn't slicing

Comment: @L3viathan, ...though the answer there *does* also describe indexing into a list as-such as well.

Comment: @SergioAlvarezPinto I'd suggest logging `repr(h.request(url,'GET'))` somewhere you can inspect it. You'll see that it has two parts, and that they materially differ from each other (one being head, the other being body content) in a way that makes the necessity to use the 2nd one to parse as JSON (when the returned body is in fact JSON) obvious.

Comment: (This is much more a question about `httplib2`, btw; it has very little to do with `json.loads()`).